# UITestException not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to a create coded UI test for my WPF program but I get this exception when I click Generate Code:

> Type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException' in
>   Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Steps I followed:

1. I created an example solution, put only a button in the WPF form
2. Ran the program
3. Added a coded UI test project to my solution
4. Started recording
5. Clicked the button
6. Paused recording
7. Clicked "Generate Code" and then "Add and Generate"

This is when I get the exception. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Walkthrough: Creating, Editing and Maintaining a Coded UI Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977233.aspx) after posting the question. Turns out I should have started the program after starting the recording.

For future referance:

1. Add a coded UI test.
2. Start the exe file from the project's bin/Debug folder.
3. Start recording.
4. Click stuff.
5. Close the exe.
6. Pause recording and generate code.